# Custom APEX Reports

Tags: sql, database-design, oracle-apex-5

Is it possible to have columns in a table with numeric and time/date values to be summed, averaged, etc on a report in APEX?

For example we may have a table that has the following columns:

```
Num_of_Calls
Num_of_Email
```

But after a month of data being entered we want to sum the num of calls column and num of emails column. So my thought was to add the following:

```
Num_of_Calls
Tot_Num_of_Calls
Num_of_Email
Tot_Num_of_Calls
```

In the TOT columns have the monthly total in there. So my question is, should I create these Tot columns to store the data after it's been calculated, or is it better to have APEX just create the calculation on the fly for us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by Aggregate and compute options available under Actions menu of the interactive reports.